# RDS upgrade to large from small

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

I am running a Small RDS of Mysql 5.1 instance with Multi AZ on. I need to upgrade to large instance now. What will be the down time of the RDS instance while upgrading it. Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had one to two minutes of downtime when I did this on my multiAZ setup a while back.

You could fire up a test instance and do a dry-run on it to be sure.